# LED lights and heatsink

Tags: led, heatsink, 12v

I want to make a light for my boat roof. If I were to buy [these](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/10x-G4-6-SMD-5050-LED-Day-White-Light-Lamp-Marine-Car-Boat-Bulb-DC12V-/111293864287?pt=UK_Light_Bulbs&hash=item19e9a1995f) (or similar), would I need to mount them to a heatsink, or would they be fine just as is?

The largest size one has a power output of 0.9W.

I would like to add some to the underneath of a counter (superglue if it doesn't get too hot, or silicone maybe?), and replace a couple of florescent tubes in light boxes.

Here's the image so you don't have to go via the link (and future-proof the question)[image: LED]

Comment: How many Watts will this LED assembly have to dissipate?

Comment: What (watt LOL) does the data sheet say?

Comment: @Nick 0.9 W for a larger 24 LED one.

Comment: I'd like to put some in existing light-boxes to replace the flourecent tubes in there, and I'd also like to attach some to the top of the cupboards so we can see in there! (Superglue to the wood If heat won't be an issue...)

Comment: @Adam glue (or screw) a metal plate to the cupboards and then use thermal paste to glue the leds on.

Comment: @Passerby Good idea. I have thermal paste left over from a computer job I did. Will these be OK or do I need a special more sticky thermal paste? Cheers

Comment: @Adam maybe, I think something like run of the mill JB Weld metal epoxy would work. Then again, looking at the picture again, those are standard 5050 leds. Heating won't really be a concern, and the pictures of the back, they arn't designed for mounting like 1W or higher led stars would be. These are basically like the simple led strips are. Don't worry about heatsinking.

Comment: Thanks @Passerby - I'll just go ahead without the heatsink. I'd accept this comment as an answer if I could. I'll check back later to see if you've made it an official answer, if not I'll accept the answer below. Thanks again.

Comment: @Adam I wrote out a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, high wattage LEDs can use passive cooling, if calculated correctly. The higher the wattage, the more crucial it is. Math aside (because I don't have it), it's essentially some square inches/cm of copper or similar per watt of heat. Finned heatsinks provide a high area in a small package. Alternatively, you can use fans or pelters or other active cooling methods.

But Even 1W led stars can use a simple metal plate to provide that passive cooling. As long as you have good thermal conduction (i.e. metal on metal or through thermal conductive material), a large metal plate works great. Metal U or N channel as well. Steel, Aluminum, Copper (if you have the money), not really crucial which.

Screw or glue a metal plate to the cupboard underside then affix the led module to it. You can use special thermal epoxy, or even something like JB Metal Weld. I am not sure how well standard thermal paste for cpus (Artic Silver) will work. When old and dried, thermal paste can hold it in place, but when fresh, it might not hold a module upside down. Some led modules can just be screwed onto the plate (Pre-drill a smaller hole, and use self tapping screws, or nuts and bolts (if you have access to the other side), or use a tapping set).

Then again, looking at the picture again, those are standard 5050 leds. Heating won't really be a concern, and the pictures of the back, they arn't designed for mounting like 1W or higher led stars would be. These are basically like the simple led strips are. Don't worry about heatsinking. These can be superglued or even hotglued.

Comment: Perfect - the most detailed and clear answer I could have hoped for. Thanks!